# How can I implement 'Forward Delete' in a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, key, android-softkeyboard, forward-delete

I am developing a custom keyboard for android. I am using `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT` for left and right arrow keys. Now I want to have forward delete key like usual keyboards and unfortunately android supports it from api level 11 using constant `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL`. How can I implement forward key delete for lower Apis?

The constant value of `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL` is 112. when I use its value instead, it print out character `p`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could move the cursor to the side and backspace, but that would be a messy solution..

Comment: @JavaNut13 How can I implement it?

Comment: Can you emulate a right-hand arrow key? Because that's all you really need to do, after that you just do a normal backspace.

Comment: It is visible for user that it has two steps and it is bad. Any other solution? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(0, 1);
```